# MapItemsControl does not reflect removing of corresponding ItemsSource

Tags: binding, uwp, observable, itemssource, uwp-maps

Within a UWP-App (Windows 10) I've got a `MapControl` and I'm using `MapItemsControl` to deliver an overlay for that map. The `ItemsSource` of that `MapItemsControl` (which is an `ObservableCollection`) is bound via xaml, but is only working in one direction:

Adding items to that collection is working fine and those items are shown in that `MapControl` too.
Removing items to that collection is working too, but seemingly only within that collection - the visual representation on my `MapControl` does not react to removing elements. This can lead to infinite adding of items into that map, while no item gets ever removed.

The `ObservableCollection` gets updated quiet frequentely (via `MapControl.ZoomLevelChanged-Event`) and gets cleared & repopulated in that process - might that be a problem?

Binding via xaml looks like this:

```
 <maps:MapControl
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    [...]>
    <maps:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind Path=MapDirectionOverlay, Mode=OneWay}"/>
</maps:MapControl>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since using [Clear-Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132405(v=vs.110).aspx) did not do the trick, I tried using other remove-methods of the `ObservableCollection` and eventually that worked.

So in the end, this is the workaround I'm using:

```
private new void Clear()
{
    for (int i = this.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        this.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

After all I still don't get, why a simple `Clear` would not work, since it still should raise a `NotifyCollectionChangedAction`. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

> Removing items to that collection is working too, but seemingly only within that collection- the visual representation on my MapControl does not react to removing elements.

[ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed. So if you add or remove items, the collection and `ItemsSouce` of binding should be reflect updated.

Since I don't know how you removing the item, by using remove methods of `ObeservableCollection` such as [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413(v=vs.110).aspx),[RemoveAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132414(v=vs.110).aspx) and [RemoveItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654938(v=vs.110).aspx), they should work well with removing items as well as removing correspondent item in the map.

But if you just set the `ObeservableCollection` to `null` will take no effect on the `ItemsSouce`.In this scenario you need to set the `ItemsSouce` of [`MapItemsControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapitemscontrol.aspx) to null manually but which is not recommend.

Comment: I'm using [Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132405(v=vs.110).aspx) to remove items from my ObeservableCollection - still the visual representation of those items justs adds up new items, but never removes them...